# Using 3 external displays with the rMBP 13"?

Tags: macbook-pro

I would like to replace my main dev machine (currently a custom built desktop machine) with a Macbook Pro. I have been using three external 24" 1920x1200 displays for many years now and found this setup to be very productive and want to keep using it after switching to a Mac. Now, with previous Macbook Pros such a setup was problematic, but I saw that this is now possible with at least the rMBP 15" by using 2 Thunderbold + 1 HDMI connections. Is this also an option with the rMBP 13"? If so, would this work well or is the Intel graphic chip in the rMBP 13" too slow for this?

Comment: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/87712/how-many-monitors-can-the-13-retina-macbook-pro-output-to